# Opening Excel with c#; sometime without menus or Window border

Tags: c#, excel

From time to time I get reports from clients, and even from our QA, that opening excel from within our WinForms app causes Excel to open without its menus and window border. Only the formulabar and the sheet is seen floating around.
This is reported to be very sporadic and I have never been ale to reproduce it myself in a develop environment and are clueless on what might be causing this.

Its been reported both with Excel 2003 and 2007.

Code:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new ApplicationClass
                       {
                           Visible = true,
                           WindowState = XlWindowState.xlNormal,
                           UserControl = true,
                           DisplayFullScreen = false,
                       };


 Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:/excel_test.xls",
                                              0, 
                                              false, 
                                              5, 
                                              "", 
                                              "", 
                                              false,
                                              XlPlatform.xlWindows, 
                                              "",
                                              true, 
                                              false, 
                                              0, 
                                              true, 
                                              false, 
                                              false);
```

Anyone that has an idea on whats wrong with this code or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the different properties that can be set on the application class? Some of them might be of use to you. Always try to be on the safe side, i.e prefer setting a lot of parameters (even the ones you think need not be set), such as fullscreen = false etc, just to eliminate possible errors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass_properties(v=office.11).aspx